# C# Why can partial methods use ref, but not out?

Tags: c#, partial-methods

Pretty straight forward. MSDN states that you can use ref, but not out for partial methods. I'm just curious as to the *why*? It was my understanding that when code is compiled, the partials are merged, so what is up with the restriction? Is there more to `partial` than just making code files cleaner and organized (i.e. eyecandy)?

Reference: [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) - "Partial methods can have [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) but not [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) parameters."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You got to consider what happens if the partial method isn't implemented.

What happens then is that all calls to the method is just stripped out as though they never happened.

So for a method using out, it would look like this:

```
stream s;
GetStream(out s);
s.Write(...);
```

and be compiled as though it said this:

```
stream s;
s.Write(...);
```

This code is not allowed because `s` has not been initialized. The guarantee that the variable would be initialized by the time you try to call the `Write` method on it was tied up with the call to `GetStream`.

It is the same with methods returning data. Since the entire method call is just not compiled if you haven't implemented the partial method, you need to consider what you can and cannot do and still leave the code that calls it valid. In terms of `out` and return values, it has the potential of leaving the calling code invalid or incomplete, so it is not allowed.

As for `ref`, that is valid since the initialization has been taken care of by the calling code:

```
stream s = null;
GetStream(ref s); // may be stripped out
if (s != null)
    s.Write(...);
```

Answer (score 9):

Because unlike ref parameters, out parameters MUST be initialized before the method returns. If the partial method is not implemented (which is a valid scenario,) how can it be initialized?

Comment: and uninitialized value type is not legal in c# compiler. good explanation

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be because `out` parameters don't need to be initialized whereas `ref` parameters do.

If you used an `out` parameter on a partial method, how could C# verify that the parameter was initialized or not?

Answer (score 4):

An `out` parameter suggests that you want a value out of the method. If the method doesn't exist, it can't provide that value.

The alternative would be to set the variable's value explicitly to its default value (0, null etc) instead of executing the method call. That way the variable would still be definitely initialized - although the default value may not be a terribly useful one. I believe the C# team have considered this - it may even make it into a future version, who knows? Personally I doubt that it would be particularly useful, but the possibility is there.

For the moment, you could always use a `ref` parameter instead, and just initialize the variable manually before the call to whatever the default value should be.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the reason is because a partial method with only a signature (i.e. no implementation) is still valid. If you had an out parameter an implementation-less method would always cause an error (as there's nothing assigning the out value)

Answer (score 1):

A partial method is split across partial classes. A method is required to assign a value to an OUT parameter. Partial methods may or may not be implemented. It would mean multiple code chunks is trying to assign value to the OUT parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has stated `out` params must be assigned. To add this will generate compiler error [CS0177](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fzd768w(VS.80).aspx) `ref` on the other hand must be assigned prior to making the call.